# Is "in the hopes of" synonymous to "in the hope of"?

Tags: idioms

Why do sometimes people put an s after hope in the idiom "in the hopes of"? Is there a reason for this, or is it just a matter of "dumb" preference? I am asking, because I saw the idiom with an s and without an s, and they both seem to be very prevalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20(the)%20hope%20of/that) of **in (the) hope of**:

> with the hope that something will happen or could happen.

From what I saw so far,

- if you wanna use *the*, we'll prefer to use *hope*:

> He returned to the crime scene in (the) hope of finding further
>   evidence.

- and if you don't use *the* we'ill rather write *hopes*:

> He waited in hopes that she would show up.

However I didn't find any official rules about it.